# Initial value from an input element of type 'number' is Empty - React and Tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am working on a react POS app with Typescript. I want to calculate the change when the I enter a the amount of money received from a buyer. When I enter the value into the input element, the first value passed to the logic that calculates the change is an empty value then the other values are added. It causes an inaccurate calculation.

```
const CartBill: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  const [change, setChange] = useState<number>(0)
//logic to calculate change
const calculateChange: changeCalculatorType = (amountReceived) => {

    if (amountReceived <= +grandTotal.toFixed(2)) {
      setChange(0);
    } else {
      const change = amountReceived - +grandTotal.toFixed(2);
      setChange(+change.toFixed(2));
    }
    return change;
  };

return(
   <div> <Received onSetChange={calculateChange} /> </div>
   <div>{change}</div>
)
}
```

this is the  component that contains the input element. It lifts the  `amount` state up to the  `CartBill` component

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import { changeCalculatorType } from '../../types/ReceivedComponentTypes';




const Received: React.FC<{ onSetChange: changeCalculatorType }> = (props) => {
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0);

  const getInputHandler = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const retrieved = +(event.target as HTMLInputElement).value.trim();
    
    setAmount(retrieved);
    props.onSetChange(amount);
   
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input type="number" name="" id="" onChange={getInputHandler} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Received
```

I tried `trim()`ing the value but that doesn't seem to work. Any help is hugely appreciated

Comment: how about check if its empty or bigger than 0 before adding it in the logic? on your code here     props.onSetChange(amount); trigger the event handler only when a value is entered

Comment: yh , tried that and it didn't really work

Comment: When exactly are you seeing the blank value?  Are you deleting out a value from the textbox and then typing in your next number?  The onChange fires with each character typed so deleting out a value will result in a '' being sent.  You could also consider onBlur to wait until tabbing out or losing focus before triggering the change.  I also noticed you're sending amount to props.onSetChange...this will always be one value behind the current because the line above is doing setAmount(retrieved), but will trigger a component update with the new 'amount' value

Comment: @mheskamp removing the setAmount() solved the issue. Thanks for drawing my attention

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value attribute on your `input`.

```js
return (
  <input type="number" name="" id="" value={amount} onChange={getInputHandler} />
);
```

Comment: thanks for this, but i already tried this and it didn't work